# What is the origin of "être branché" in the sense of "à la mode" ?

Tags: argot, origine-ou-raison

I've noticed that this expression is familiarly used to indicate something being in style, cool, or generally "à la mode" - notably [here on this stack exchange site](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/13382/difference-between-en-vogue-and-%C3%A0-la-mode/13385#13385).

Does anyone know the origin of this usage ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is related to *brancher* as in :

> brancher une conduite (une canalisation) à un circuit principal.

voir *branchement **électrique***.
*Branché* recently received (particularly among youngsters) the meaning of:

> mis au **courant**, concerné (1973)

and took by extension the meaning of :

> à la mode, dans le coup (1980).

*Cablé* (1980) as the same meaning.
Source: Dictionnaire historique de la langue française, Alain Rey. Approximate translation.
Those of us who are more than forty may remember the interview of F. Mitterrand by Y. Mourousi ;) see [the video from INA](https://youtu.be/dBqhuL-rmVI?t=116)

Answer (score 0):

I would say that it is something derivated from the [**avoir de la branche**](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/avoir_de_la_branche) expression :

1. Avoir de l’allure, de la distinction.
2. (Généalogie) Appartenir à la noblesse, avoir des ancêtres issus de
   la noblesse.

So the origin would come from the prestige of being part of a noble family tree (Arbre généalogique).